Can a man wear a "women's watch"?
It's generally forbidden for a man to wear a woman's garment.  (Source.)
A common type of wristwatch is the "women's watch".  Some are red or pink.  They're often smaller than men's watches.
Is a man allowed to wear a women's watch?
If you cite sources, please preferably cite Modern Orthodox ones.  Thanks!
Possibly related

Can a woman wear a "men's watch"?
What are the opinions on men wearing a wrist watch? Is it considered beged isha?

